# Prove that $f(x) =1/x^2$ is continuous on its domain $(0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

> Prove that the function $\smash{\dfrac{1}{x^2}}$ is continuous on its domain $(0,∞)$.

Proof:
$$
\lim_{x \to a} \frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{1}{a^2} 
$$

After manipulating I would get
$$ 
\frac{(x-a)(x+a)}{x^2 a^2} 
$$
where $x+a < 1 + 2\lvert a \rvert$

What do I do to the $\smash{\dfrac{1}{x^2 a^2}}$?

Comment: It's a bouned quantity near $a$ so the top going to 0 does the job for you.

Comment: Welcome to SE - please learn to use MathJax to typeset your math - I've done most of it here so others can read the problem - you can try to finish it.

Comment: Where does your "$x+a < 1 + 2\lvert a \rvert$" come from?

Comment: Start with you’re $\epsilon$ bound and work your way backwords to find $\delta$ which depends on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Is it possibile to apply arithmetic properties of the limit ? If so  the function $g(x)=x$ is continuous, hence $h(x)=g(x)g(x)=x^2$ is continuous. Finally the function $f(x)=1/h(x)=1/x^2$ is continuous. All the functions are considered as mappings from $(0,\infty)$ to itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Prove that $f(x)=1/x^2$
> is continuous on its domain $(0,\infty)$

Let proof for $x\in [1,\infty)$,

We have that,
$$\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(c)| &= \left|\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{c^2}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{c^2-x^2}{x^2c^2}\right|\\
&= \left|\frac{x+c}{x^2c^2}\right| |x-c|\\
&= \left|\frac{x}{x^2c^2}+\frac{c}{x^2c^2}\right| |x-c|.
\end{align*}$$

Now, $|x|\leq x^2[\because x\in [1,\infty)]$ implies that $\frac{|x|}{x^2}\leq 1$ and therefore
$$ \frac{|x|}{x^2c^2} \leq \frac{1}{c^2} \leq 1$$

It follows that $|f(x)-f(c)|\leq 2|x-c|$. Hence given $\epsilon>0$ we let $\delta=\epsilon/2$ and if $|x-c|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(c)| \lt \epsilon$.

For $x\in (0,1)$, See [The answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1511789/1213102)